# How we can find attach function in a html tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have a html tag and some javascript function is attached on that by addEvenetListner or attachEvent (with tag id or name but not inline), and if we need find out that which function is attach on that tag, then what is good way for find that.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

If don't need to do it programmatically you can use [visual event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event). If you need to do it programmatically i only have a jquery solution (`$('#element').data('events');`)

Answer (score 0):

There is no native API to get event handler that was attached by addEventListener/attachEvent. jQuery store internal this handlers in some object. If you use jQuery you can done this by:

```
$('#someID').data('events');
```

Or you can write wrapper for addEventListener/attachEvent and store handlers manualy.